# New route events based on existing route events' locations/values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation, linear-referencing

[image]

The goal is continuous values along a line based on known values of certain segments along the line. I was pointed towards linear referencing an an approach, so am currently trying to derive the values of the empty route events from their two neighboring route events (probably a distance weighted average).

Problem:

I need to assign values to the empty route events based on neighboring route events' values. Are there any tools or extensions compatible with a basic license that would do this?

The most similar question I have come across is https://geonet.esri.com/thread/98223, but that was points, not lines (so not continuous like I want), and it used Calculate Geometry to calculate the X value, which I don't have and am not interested in, so I can't use calculate geometry like they did.

I read about linear interpolation methods, but they are much(!) more statistically complex than I have the skills or time to even consider.

Is there a better/non-linear referencing/non-gis option for accomplishing this?

Comment: This looks like it needs linear referencing to me.  For the first point where you are stuck what precisely did you try and where precisely are you stuck? I recommend removing anything unrelated to that particular problem from this question.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Posting actually jogged my brain on the first problem; I will do a spatial join of the shapefile my field of interest is in to the file my route events would be based on. I will have route events for the entire route and will need to calculate the field of interest in the even segments where there is no data. I hope that seems reasonable. I think I really need help with the second (now only) problem in my post: I can't figure out a way to interpolate data for points in between the segments with known values.

Comment: I think your question may distil to whether there is a Basic license level workaround to Generate Near Table so I think you should keep editing to try and make what you are asking clearer.

Comment: That isn't the question I was trying to ask; Generate Near Table was just one tool I thought might be somewhat helpful for part of the process. I wanted to make clear some of the tools I had looked at/my thinking about the process and that any tool suggested would need to be included in the Basic license level.

Comment: Perhaps you can work on tying your question text into your picture - at the moment the picture seems too simple to be of any help.

Comment: You make no mention of ArcPy in your question, and have not included a code snippet, so I have removed that tag.

Answer (score 2):

To 'fill in the blanks' of line segments, you could create an event that covers the whole line.  Then you can dissolve route events (linear referencing toolbox).

Another option is to bring your event table into excel and create records for the blank spaces and assign whatever values you want to the blank records.  To do this, you would assign the end measure of the previous segment as the start measure of the blank segment, and the start measure of the following segment as the end measure of the blank segment.  Once you have done this, use the modified table to create the route events to cover the entire line.

E.g. :
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I ended up joining the features I had to another shapefile I found that covered the entire extent of the route.